# Expression Trees reuse Values?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, lambda, expression-trees

Im reading Jon Skeet book. ( Expression Trees Chapter)
It has an example of creating expression tree out of lambda Expressions :

```
Expression<Func<string, string, bool>> expression =    (x, y) => x.StartsWith(y);
var compiled = expression.Compile();
Console.WriteLine(compiled("First", "Second"));
Console.WriteLine(compiled("First", "Fir"));
```

Now he is doing the same with expression tree :

[image]

question :

The *yellow* part *already* includes  the params info !

why Do I have to specify AGAIN in the *blue* part those param ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your question is:

> Why can't `Expression.Lambda` inspect the entire expression-body for
>   parameter-expressions and then use them as the expression-parameters, relieving me of the trouble of having to explicitly hand them over again in the `Lambda` call?

Well, it certainly could, but how would it know in what  *order* to accept those parameters in the general case?

In your example, how would it know whether to generate the expression-equivalent of:

```
(x, y) => x.StartsWith(y)
```

(or)

```
(y, x) => x.StartsWith(y)?
```

Should your `lambda.Compile()("42", "4")` return `true` or `false`?

It can't make these decisions on your behalf in the general case.

Comment: in this line `Expression call = Expression.Call(target, method, methodArgs);` I told him what is the order ! the first is x  , second is the method , and the third is the argument !

Comment: @Royi: That's not the order in which the parameters are *accepted* by the top-level lambda, that's how the parameters are *used* in that particular sub-expression.